# Whats wrong with my Redirect 301 Regex?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

**Google Search Console has some crawl errors and can't find these links:**

```
home-third-blog-posts/page/10/
home-third-blog-posts/page/5/
home-third-blog-posts/page/7/
home-third-blog-posts/page/9/
```

**And my Redirect rule in .htacces looks like this**

```
Redirect 301 /\/home-third-blog-posts\/.*/s http://foo.com
```

My Regex-Tester says its correct but when i test the links the redirect doesn't work. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`Redirect` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirect), you'll see that it **does not** accept regex/patterns. You should be using the [`RedirectMatch`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /home-third-blog-posts/.* http://foo.com
```

also, no need to escape the `/` characters.